# Using Unicode Arrows, But the Tail of Arrow is on the Point, Not the Tip

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have successfully used Unicode arrows to make my points. However, the pointy part of the arrow isn't actually pointing at the coordinate I'm trying to graph, the tail end (the flat part of the arrow) is pointing at the desired coordinate. How can I position these arrows so that the pointed tip is on the point.

I'm new to python, so the more "dumbed down" your answer, the better.

Thank you so much.

```
#import stuff
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import pylab 

 #set my arrow equal to unicode code for the arrow I wanted

    arrow = u'$\u2193$'

#plotted my figures (I haven't shown the part of the code where I read in all that stuff)

    f1 = plt.figure('Figure 1')
    plt.scatter(days,fluxdensity,label='4.5 GHz', marker=arrow,s=400,alpha=.5)
    plt.scatter(days2, fluxdensity2, color='red',label='7.4 GHz', marker=arrow,s=1000)
    plt.scatter(days3, fluxdensity3, color='magenta', label='20 GHz', marker=arrow,s=800)
    plt.scatter(days4, fluxdensity4, color='green', label= '24 GHz', marker=arrow,s=400,alpha=.5)
    pylab.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.grid()

    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xscale('log')


    plt.xlabel('Days Since Explosion', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('Flux Density muJy', fontsize=16)
    plt.savefig('2014dtflux.pdf',format='pdf')

    plt.show()
```

[image: A picture of my plot where it shows the ends of the arrows pointing at the coordinate I'm plotting instead of the triangular end]

Comment: Use the arrow that [points the other way](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2191/index.htm)?

Comment: I need to use the downward pointing arrow, and anyway, it still puts the point at the tail of the arrow.

Comment: I suggest you reconsider your tag choice to get attention from the right people. I don't think your problem is `unicode`-related, and for `arrow`, the description actually tells you not to use that tag! You should tag your question with `matplotlib`.

Comment: Ok, I will do that! Thank you!